# Can anyone explain this vbs code.line by line

Tags: vbscript

all.

I want to understand this code line by line can any one help me. please.
I am Writing document on this.

Thanks

```
   Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

If WScript.Arguments.Count < 1 Then
WScript.Quit
End If
  objStartFolder = objFSO.GetAbsolutePathName(WScript.Arguments(0))
  Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(objStartFolder)
  Set colFiles = objFolder.Files

For Each objFile in colFiles
strFileName = objFile.Name
If objFSO.GetExtensionName(strFileName) = "xml" Then
            objFSO.CopyFile objFile.Name, "TMP.xml", True
            Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
            Set xlBook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("c:/Users/xyz/Desktop/vbs/xyz.xlsm", 0, False)
            objExcel.Run "importxml", objStartFolder & "/TMP.xml",  objStartFolder & "/out.xml"
            xlBook.Close (False)
            objExcel.Quit
            Set xlBook = Nothing
            Set objExcel = Nothing
            objFSO.CopyFile "out.xml", objFile.Name & "_out.xml", True
 End If
  Next
objFSO.DeleteFile "TMP.xml", True   
objFSO.DeleteFile "out.xml", True 
WScript.Quit
```

Comment: SO is not to help you understand your code. That's your homework.

Comment: I want to use this code in my work but I have only brife idea About what it does. and I want to know line by line before  I actually use.

Comment: @aaakanks it's pretty self explanatory, if you don't understand what it is doing you shouldn't be attempting to use it.

Comment: Mr.Lankymart ,Stackover flow is just for that as far as I know If any one can not understand somthing genius people like you can help right?Am I wrong? You know that stuff and some people don't.this site is hope for them. you can not say like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with Andy's comment about SO is to answer specific questions.  However, the brief gist of what that VB Script is doing is:

1. It checks to see if the script was invoked with a command line argument of a valid folder path.
2. For each XML file in that folder it creates a copy of the XML file.
3. Excel is called to open a specific XLSM file. (NOTE: XLSM files are macro-enabled spreadsheets)
4. The macro in the spreadsheet is called passing in as arguments the copied XML file name, and, presumably, a file name that the macro should write it's results to.
5. Then XML files are copied and cleaned up.